# How can save custom attribute value from product_form.xml Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

Add new attribute in product create page in admin side

**How can I save value from  this dropdown?**

here is my product_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="product-details">
        <field name="featured_category_ids" sortOrder="100" formElement="select" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Featured Categories</label>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: how you create this attribute?

Comment: add this product_form.xml file in my module and its are visible in adminside but value not save

Comment: You need to just create the product attribute using magento methods only and assign that attributeset, rest things is manage by magneto it self.

Comment: can you sow me working example? or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a product attribute and add it to the product's attribute set first.

Then, reference the attribute ID in your field dataScope like so:

```
        <field name="attribute_id" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <dataScope>attribute_id</dataScope>
                <imports>
                    <link name="linkedValue">${$.provider}:data.product.attribute_id</link>
                </imports>
            </settings>
        </field>
```

If the two IDs match, Magento will save the value.

Answer (score 0):

should be hidden or visible?
can you leave a more complete code for creating product_form.xml fields through and creating and saving an attribute?
My code which doesn't save or output attribute

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="product_duo" sortOrder="6">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Duo</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <opened>true</opened>
            <dataScope>product_duo</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <field name="duo_product" formElement="input" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/input</elementTmpl>
                <label translate="true">Duo product</label>
                <dataScope>duo_product</dataScope>
                <imports>
                    <link name="linkedValue">${$.provider}:data.product.duo_product</link>
                </imports>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>

$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'duo_product',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'backend'  => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => __('Duo product'),
                'input' => 'hidden',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'  => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'unique'  => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'is_configurable' => false,
            ]
```